# Why do MATLAB and R give different results for Wilcoxon signed rank test?

Tags: r, matlab, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have tried to calculate Wilcoxon signed rank test p-values using MATLAB and R. Strangely, they give different results. Concretely, my code for MATLAB is

```
a = [2 1 3 4 1];
b = [5 2 1 0 5];
signrank(a, b, 'method', 'approximate');
```

The result is p = 0.7865.

For R,

```
a = c(2, 1, 3, 4, 1)
b = c(5, 2, 1, 0, 5)
wilcox.test(a, b, paired = TRUE)
```

The result is p = 0.8923.

I wonder why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

R applies a correction by default

```r
a = c(2, 1, 3, 4, 1)
b = c(5, 2, 1, 0, 5)
wilcox.test(a, b, paired = TRUE, correct = FALSE, exact = FALSE)

>>>
Wilcoxon signed rank test

data:  a and b
V = 6.5, p-value = 0.7865
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

R often will add a correction by default (see `chisq.test` for another instance of this happening).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! One more question though: How can I decide whether to keep the correction or not?

Comment: @fdls2011 My recommendation is to apply the correction always.